# Throw error from zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, error-handling, zend-framework2, throw

I am creating APIs using zend framework. Is there any mechanism to throw a error in zend framework?

something like Frapi

**throw new Frapi_Error('Internal Server Error');**

One way is throw exception, catch it and return as a json response. But that way I have to write that code in try and catch block.

What's people normally use to throw a error from zend?

Comment: You only `throw` exceptions, not errors.

Comment: throw exceptions, then attach a listener to catch the exception and display an appropriate message to the user

Comment: Can I create a single class which listens to all class's throw exceptions and call this class before returning the response to user? Because that way I don't have to write catch in all classes.

Comment: @BSThakrar, Yes. You can use [set_exception_handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php).

Comment: ok. Thanks. I will try this and wait for zend to release any built in error handling mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

There is no dedicated "error handling mechanism" in Zend Framework 2 and there won't ever be one. An Error is an `Exception` and needs to be treated as such.

Now since you've talked about returning Responses I'm assuming some kind of API. In this case you may want to check out [`zfcamput\ZF\ApiProblem`](https://github.com/zfcampus/zf-api-problem) and the use of that thing within the shiny [`Apigility`](http://apigility.org/). You may want to read further opon the topic of API in Matthews great posts here

- [Restful APIs with ZF2 - Part 1](http://mwop.net/blog/2013-02-11-restful-apis-with-zf2-part-1.html)
- [Restful APIs with ZF2 - Part 2](http://mwop.net/blog/2013-02-13-restful-apis-with-zf2-part-2.html)
- [Restful APIs with ZF2 - Part 3](http://mwop.net/blog/2013-02-25-restful-apis-with-zf2-part-3.html)

ZF2 Itself will catch all Exceptions, too, and ultimately return them in an error page. But really Exceptions shouldn't happen / be displayed tot he user at any time. So writing dedicated `try/catch` statements and tell the user how to fix things is the best approach you can do.

Comment: Ok. thanks I will try this. But do you happen to know that it supports DynamoDB or not ?

Comment: This literally has NOTHING to do with the DBMS at all. Error Handling is the task of your application.

Answer (score 0):

you can create your own custom exception class if you want.

```
   /**
 * Create a class to test the exception
 */
class TestException
{
    public $var;

    const THROW_NONE    = 0;
    const THROW_CUSTOM  = 1;
    const THROW_DEFAULT = 2;

    function __construct($avalue = self::THROW_NONE) {

        switch ($avalue) {
            case self::THROW_CUSTOM:
                // throw custom exception
                throw new MyException('1 is an invalid parameter', 5);
                break;

            case self::THROW_DEFAULT:
                // throw default one.
                throw new Exception('2 is not allowed as a parameter', 6);
                break;

            default: 
                // No exception, object will be created.
                $this->var = $avalue;
                break;
        }
    }
}


// Example 1
try {
    $o = new TestException(TestException::THROW_CUSTOM);
} catch (MyException $e) {      // Will be caught
    echo "Caught my exception\n", $e;
    $e->customFunction();
} catch (Exception $e) {        // Skipped
    echo "Caught Default Exception\n", $e;
}
```

Comment: I like this idea of creating a class for this. Is there any way in which I don't have to write this try/catch block from where I want to throw a exception ?